# How to remove nodes at the start of a linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, queue, nodes

I have this list : [**5,3**,5,**5,3**,7,7,**5,3**,2]
and I need to remove every time I have a sequence in the list which is the same as a queue given to me - for example the queue [exit-**5,3**-enter] my function returns
[5,3,5,7,7,2-->null] but I want it to be [5,7,7,2-->null].
I would also like to mention that when I am talking about a linked list I actually mean a list of nodes-

```
Node<Integer> lis
```

(it has a value and a pointer to the next node). I already did the function I mentioned but what I did doesn't work if the sequence appears at the start of the list-like Iv'e already mentioned because I don't know how to remove from the start of the list. I know how to remove a node I just reference to next Nodes and leave it with no reference but my function gets a copy of the main reference to the list

```
 public static void removeAppear(Node<Integer> n,Queue<Integer> q){
```

so if I would just write :

```
n=n.getNext();
```

for example it won't actually delete the first node, and from the void main method I would still see the first node. If you need the function I did say so but I really just need to know how to delete a first node.Sorry if it's a basic question but i'm quite new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t mutate a linked list to remove leading nodes, unless you stop thinking of your function as ‘changing the list’ and start thinking of it as ‘returning a new list which is different from the original’. Then it can return a reference to a node which was not originally the first node.